# Add external code to npm run build for index.html

Tags: facebook, vue.js, tracking

I wanna add a Tracking Code from FB to my VueJS LandingPage.

But i'm not sure where i have to place the code snippet?

```
         <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
            <script>
            !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
            {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
            n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
            if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
            n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
            t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,document,'script',
            'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
            fbq('init', 'xxxxxx'); 
            fbq('track', 'PageView');
                    </script>
            <noscript>
             <img height="1" width="1" 
            src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=xxxxxx&ev=PageView
            &noscript=1"/>
            </noscript>
            <!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

If i copy this code by myself to the index.html it work. but where i have to place this snippet that it will copy in my index.html build?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just leave it in index.html?  It'll be in the build output if it's in there.

Comment: i use the package vue-form-wizard and i want to fire the event only if the user come to the last page of the form

Comment: I would include the script in the index.html but take out the `fbq('init', 'xxxxxx');` & `fbq('track', 'PageView');` and call those functions in the ` mounted` event of the page you want it to track at.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Vue CLI 3, you should have a `src` folder and a `public` folder. The `public` folder contains the `index.html` that is used to generate the index.html-file you see in the dist folder after building. Just add your tracker to that and it should be included in your built version as well.

You can also copy the tracker script to the `mounted` hook of App.vue, or whatever you use as your main component. Since your application will do nothing useful anyway when javascript is disabled, there is little reason to track that as well.

Comment: i use a npm package called "vue-form-wizard" and on site three.. i want to display the snippet. can you show me an example how to copy the snippet in the component? if i copy one by one it doesnt work

Comment: You should not copy the script into a component. There should be an index.html file somewhere you can put the snippet in. Remember that you are only tracking that your app was loaded and nothing else, since any route changes are not recorded. `vue-form-wizard` seems to be just a component, so I don't think it makes any difference.

Comment: What is the command that `npm run build` runs if you look in your package.json?

Comment: That is Vue CLI 3, so I would assume the explanation above to work. You have to put it in index.html in the public folder, not in index.html in the dist folder and not in App.vue.